# Xamp can't start xamp(apache) on another port different from 80

Tags: apache, xampp

```
8:39:07  [Apache]   Attempting to start Apache service...
8:39:07  [Apache]   XAMPP Apache is already running on port 80
8:39:07  [Apache]   XAMPP Apache is already running on port 443
```

my xamp tells me that apache is already running, but I can't start it when I press the button "start" in my xamp, I even have changed the port to 8080, but nothing changed, why this happens?

Comment: It may not be Apache that's running, it could be some other service. On Mac OSX, Apache is a system service which you can enable, maybe you've done that? (Assuming you use OSX...)

What OS are you using?

Comment: @JeffHuijsmans I'am using windows, no, no other service I can see there, the problem is that http://localhost is available after initializing XAMP, but I can't configure the httpd.conf for it, and also why there is a button "start" if it is automatically executed, can't understand this moment